# App crashing on button click

Tags: java, android

Whenever I click my button my app crashes. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            int primaryLength = PRIMARY.length;
            final String primaryText = PRIMARY[rnd.nextInt(primaryLength)];
            int secondaryLength = SECONDARY.length;
            final String secondaryText = SECONDARY[rnd.nextInt(secondaryLength)];
            final TextView textOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            final TextView textTwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textOne.setText(primaryText);
            textTwo.setText(secondaryText);

            String primeT = primaryText;
            Uri media = Uri.parse(primeT);
            mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, media);
            mpButtonOne.start();
            mpButtonOne.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpButtonOne) {
                    String primeS = secondaryText;
                    Uri media2 = Uri.parse(primeS);
                    mpButtonTwo = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, media2);
                    mpButtonTwo.start();
                    mpButtonTwo.setOnCompletionListener(new soundListener1());
                    {
                    }
                }
```

I want the randomly selected text that is displayed in textviews to be entered as the location for the mediaplayer sound files, the words are the names of the sound files in my raw folder. I'm a bit new and really not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

```
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at com.spunktrunk.nastylittleman.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
09-11 16:50:40.128: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 16:50:40.128: W/ActivityManager(237):   Force finishing activity com.spunktrunk.nastylittleman/.MainActivity
```

Comment: please post the logcat logs...

Comment: yes, post the stacktrace

Comment: At which line are you facing the problem?

Comment: Which line is 62? Something there is `null`

Comment: Give more details, we can't know what is wrong in this code !

Comment: 62 is mpButtonOne.start();
@mansoulx I don't know what's wrong with it either which is why I'm asking

Comment: You'll have to set breakpoints and trace back through. `mpButtonOne` is `null` probably because `media` is `null` , etc... I would check at this line `final String primaryText = PRIMARY[rnd.nextInt(primaryLength)];` and make sure you are getting the expected results there

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your url, calling Media.create might have returned a null value ([look at the documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29)). If so, your code is trying to call a method on null, which causes your NPE (Null Pointer Exception)

You could of course change your code like this:

```
 mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, media);
 if (mButtonOne==null){
        //display a Toast message here
        return;
 }
 mpButtonOne.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it to stop crashing however now no sound actually plays and I get this error


    `09-11 17:44:37.568: E/PlayerDriver(200): Command    PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported
09-11 17:44:37.568: E/MediaPlayer(13621): error (1, -4)`

I think this means it can't get the audiofile? Am I creating Uri media wrong? I'm basically creating a string from a textview, changing it to Uri called media then calling that when I create my mediaplayer.

Comment: Or thinking about it is there a way to return a value of "media" back to a text view?

Comment: uri should refer to an [Uniform Resource Identifier][1]. As such it can be a local resource or one on the web. What value are you sending to the creation method?[1]http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html